# Skip mapping null properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using `AutoMapper` to map a ViewModel to a Model. However, I want properties to not be mapped if the corresponding source property is `null`.

My source class is as follows:

```
public class Source
{
    //Other fields...
    public string Id { get; set; } //This should not be mapped if null
}
```

And the destination class is:

```
public class Destination
{
    //Other fields...
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how I configured the mapper:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    //Other mappings...
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
        .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
});
```

I thought that mapping would mean that properties don't get overwritten in the destination if the source one is `null`. But apparently I'm wrong: even when `Source.Id` is null, it still gets mapped, AutoMapper assigns it an empty Guid (`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`), overwriting the existing one. How do I properly tell AutoMapper to skip mapping of a property if the source is null?

**NOTE**: I don't think this is a problem with the `Guid<->String` conversion, such conversion works in automapper, I've used it in the pass. The problem is that it's not skipping the Id property when it is null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy way would be to not have to distinguish between null and `Guid.Empty`. Like this

```
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
        .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => ((Guid)srcMember) != Guid.Empty));
```

In this case the source member is not the string value you map from, it's the resolved value that would be assigned to the destination. It's of type `Guid`, a struct, so it will never be null. A null string will map to `Guid.Empty`. See [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Conditional-mapping.html#preconditions).

Comment: Mmm... I'll try it, but I don't understand why this should work if mine doesn't... I mean, if srcMember is null your expression would return false... the same as my "srcMember != null" check in the same situation. Why should yours work if mine doesn't?

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Comment: This worked great but doesn't seem to work with `ReverseMap()`

Comment: I've just tried this and it doesn't seem to do anything, still getting empty guids.  Has anything changed with automapper?

Comment: No, you must be missing smth.