# How to not map null properties with AutoMapper

Tags: mapping, automapper

I'm trying to configure my mapping to be sure that the null value will be not mapped. I'm using *ForAllMembers* method but it wont work. (It work with a *ForMember* method).

Here's my code:

```
public void DontMapNullable()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src,dst,srcMember) => srcMember != null));
    });

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    Source source = new Source() { SomeInt = null };

    int destInt = 42;
    Destination destination = new Destination() { SomeInt = destInt };

    destination = mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source, destination);
    Assert.Equal(destInt,destination.SomeInt);
}

public class Source
{
    public int? SomeInt { get; set; } = null;
}

public class Destination
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}
```

My assert is failing because `destination.SomeInt` is 0 and not 42.
I assume that Automapper map convert a null to a int and set destination property to 0.

Comment: This has been discussed many times before, here and in the AM repo. You'll just have to use one of the workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Posting here is always my last solution and I search a lot into the documentation and here. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46099511/6224598) where you give the solution I used. Can you indicate me a link where workarounds are explained? That will be great !

Comment: That's the easy way. If you want details, you need to search the issues, not the docs.

Comment: I'll check issues to find some workarounds. Thank you for giving me this direction. Have a  nice day